# error when generating cloud endpoints java client lib: "'JavaApi' object has no attribute '_class_name'"

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I'm new to google cloud endpoints.  I've got a basic project working on the server side with one endpoint and one method. I can successfully execute the method from the API Explorer.

So now I want to generate a client lib for use in an Android app.  When I run

```
mvn appengine:endpoints_get_client_lib
```

I get the error output below.  The interesting bit is where it says "'JavaApi' object has no attribute '_class_name'".  I'm not sure what it's referring to here; I don't have anything called "JavaApi" in my code, so it must be some intermediate generated code.

Any ideas?

[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.3:endpoints_get_client_lib (default-cli) @ web-service-public ---

[INFO]

[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - Generate endpoints get client lib

[INFO] Using Class Name:com.getfitivity.webservice.pub.resource.TrainingProgramResource

[INFO] Executing endpoints Command=[get-client-lib, -cp, C:\Users\Andy\Dev\projects\fitivity\fitivity-service\web-service-public\target\classes;C:\Users\Andy\Dev\projects\fitivity\fitivity-service\web-service-public\target/classes;C:\Users\Andy.m2\repository\com\getfitivity\web-service-common\1.0-SNAPSHOT\web-service-common-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Andy.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.8.3\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\Andy.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-endpoints\1.8.3\appengine-endpoints-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\Andy.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar, -o, C:\Users\Andy\Dev\projects\fitivity\fitivity-service\web-service-public\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF, -w, C:\Users\Andy\Dev\projects\fitivity\fitivity-service\web-service-public\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints, -l, java, com.getfitivity.webservice.pub.resource.TrainingProgramResource]
Oct 02, 2013 5:59:47 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml

INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Andy\Dev\projects\fitivity\fitivity-service\web-service-public\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
API configuration written to C:\Users\Andy\Dev\projects\fitivity\fitivity-service\web-service-public\target\generated-sources\appengine-endpoints\WEB-INF/public-v1.api
API Discovery Document written to ./public-v1-rest.discovery

[ERROR] 
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error

{"error": {"message": "Internal Server Error", "code": 500, "errors": [{"message": "unknown exception", "debug_info": "'JavaApi' object has no attribute '_class_name'"}]}}

at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1050)
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.postRequest(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:53)
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.generateClientLib(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:44)
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GenClientLibAction.genClientLib(GenClientLibAction.java:67)
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GetClientLibAction.getClientLib(GetClientLibAction.java:79)
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GetClientLibAction.execute(GetClientLibAction.java:55)
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool.execute(EndpointsTool.java:67)
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool.main(EndpointsTool.java:93)
at com.google.appengine.endpoints.EndpointsMojo.executeEndpointsCommand(EndpointsMojo.java:91)
at com.google.appengine.endpoints.EndpointsGetClientLib.execute(EndpointsGetClientLib.java:55)

[... uninteresting stack levels omitted...]

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out.  The problem was my API name, as in

```
@Api(name = "foo")
```

was a java keyword (in my case "public", because I was defining a public web service API, as opposed to an administrative, internal-use one).

I tried some other java keywords like "private", "static", "for", and "switch" and got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Update your pom.xml file to utilize version 1.8.4 of the plugin and try running

`mvn clean install appengine:endpoints_get_client_lib` to do a full rebuild.

Comment: I was on 1.8.4 when I first encountered the problem.  I upgraded to 1.8.5, but that didn't help, and then I downgraded to 1.8.3, but that didn't help, either.  Same symptom.